# Can I create a re-closable flap in artificial grass to occasionally access a panel underneath?

Tags: landscaping, turf

I'll have an underground catch basin in middle of a small plot of artificial grass and I'd like to keep it covered with the artificial grass if possible.   Can I just cut a flap and put it back down for occasional access or will I need to cut out a full square completely?
Which direction should I cut the flap to make it blend in the most?

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab and say "it depends."  What kind of artificial grass?  Are you assuming that water will sufficiently drain through this artificial grass?

Comment: Greenline Fescue 65 drains 30+ inches of rain per hour - so I'm not worried about drainage... but not needed anyways since the catch basin is for a roof gutter drain line - and the catch basin has to be there for other complicated reasons.    https://greenlineartificialgrass.com/product/classic-premium-65-fescue/

Comment: So it's more a junction box than a catch basin?

Comment: Sounds like velcro...

Comment: It depends on the actual product and how you do the hinge. Who can say? Please revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: I was very tempted to VtC as opinion based... "blend" is opinion for sure or maybe decorating... The rest, honestly, who knows other than the mfgr.

Comment: "a small plot of artificial grass"   How small?  Maybe you can just roll the grass back from an edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can* you? I'm sure you can.

Will it last a long time? Who knows, maybe contact the manufacturer to ask about how many times the backing can be bent before they expect it to fail?

What's the worst case scenario for failure here - that your flap will end up tearing off and you'll have a removable piece instead of a flap? Since that's your other option, I'd say go ahead and give the flap a try.

As far as which way to cut to make the seam disappear, I think you'll have to take a look for yourself since we didn't get any pictures. You may end up having to make a couple of small samples to see if one way works better than another. For appearance related items (like paint and stain), making a test piece is always the best option. Who knows - the appearance or disappearance of the cut line may depend on which way the sun hits it. You might see it in the morning and not in the evening (or vice versa).